# SQL Server : 'Could not be bound' - Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a dynamic stored procedure, it's long so I'll just provide the part that is causing the error.

```
  SELECT  @sSql = @sSql + ' 
            animal.AnimalId,
            species.Code AS Species,
            breed.Code AS Breed ,
            country.CountryId AS CountryId ,
            country.Code AS CountryCode ,
            animal.Sex AS Sex , 
            animalRegistration.Identifier AS RegNo ,
            breed.Description + country.Code + animal.Sex + animalRegistration.Identifier AS FullRegNo,
            thePrefix.Prefix AS Prefix,
            animal.Name AS Name,
            thePrefix.Prefix + animal.Name AS FullName, 
            animal.Name AS EarTag1,
            animal.DateOfBirth as DateOfBirth ,
            0 as AnimalFlagCount'
           --isnull( Genomics.GetAnimalFlagCount( a.AnimalId,' + CAST(@IsCatalogSamples AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' ), 0) AS AnimalFlagCount '
            --a.EarTag1 
    SELECT  @sFrom = '  
         FROM dbo.Animal AS animal 
         LEFT JOIN dbo.Breed breed ON animal.BreedId = breed.BreedId
         LEFT JOIN dbo.Species species ON species.SpeciesId = breed.SpeciesId
         LEFT JOIN dbo.AnimalIdentity animalIdentity ON animalIdentity.AnimalId = animal.AnimalId
         LEFT JOIN dbo.AnimalIdentity animalRegistration ON animalRegistration.AnimalId = animal.AnimalId and  animalRegistration.IdentityTypeId = 2
         LEFT JOIN dbo.Country country ON animalIdentity.CountryId = country.CountryId
         LEFT JOIN dbo.AnimalPrefix animalPrefix ON animalPrefix.AnimalId = animal.AnimalId
         LEFT JOIN dbo.Prefix thePrefix ON thePrefix.PrefixId = animalPrefix.PrefixId 

        WHERE
        '
```

This is returning the error:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
>   The multi-part identifier "thePrefix.Prefix" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
>   The multi-part identifier "thePrefix.Prefix" could not be bound.

When I create a query using this exact statement in a different window, it returns with out issue:

```
  SELECT    
        animal.AnimalId,
        species.Code AS Species,
        breed.Code AS Breed ,
        country.CountryId AS CountryId ,
        country.Code AS CountryCode ,
        animal.Sex AS Sex , 
        animalRegistration.Identifier AS RegNo ,
        breed.Description + country.Code + animal.Sex + animalRegistration.Identifier AS FullRegNo,
        thePrefix.Prefix AS Prefix,
        animal.Name AS Name,
        thePrefix.Prefix + animal.Name AS FullName, 
        animal.Name AS EarTag1,
        animal.DateOfBirth as DateOfBirth ,
        0 as AnimalFlagCount
         FROM dbo.Animal AS animal 
         LEFT JOIN dbo.Breed breed ON animal.BreedId = breed.BreedId
         LEFT JOIN dbo.Species species ON species.SpeciesId = breed.SpeciesId
         LEFT JOIN dbo.AnimalIdentity animalIdentity ON animalIdentity.AnimalId = animal.AnimalId
         LEFT JOIN dbo.AnimalIdentity animalRegistration ON animalRegistration.AnimalId = animal.AnimalId and  animalRegistration.IdentityTypeId = 2
         LEFT JOIN dbo.Country country ON animalIdentity.CountryId = country.CountryId
         LEFT JOIN dbo.AnimalPrefix animalPrefix ON animalPrefix.AnimalId = animal.AnimalId
         LEFT JOIN dbo.Prefix thePrefix ON thePrefix.PrefixId = animalPrefix.PrefixId 
         where 
         animalRegistration.Identifier = '5573144'
```

Can anyone see why this is creating an issue? I realize it might not be possible with this much code, but I figured maybe I'm overlooking something big.

Thanks,

Comment: No offense but this "procedure" looks like a recipe for disaster. You are using dynamic sql instead of creating procedures to do the queries. This procedure is wide open to sql injection attack. And unless you are using a case sensitive collation adding a table alias that is the same as the table name is nothing but more typing.

Comment: About all I can say for debugging this is to print or select sSql + sFrom and see what the sql is before it executes. Of course, what you are facing here is one of the curses of this type of thing. You are counting on valid sql being sent in.

Comment: If you're executing `@sSql + @sFrom` there won't be a space between the two. You'll end up with `... 0 as AnimalFlagCountFROM dbo.Animal...` in the middle of your query. Try executing `@sSql + ' ' + @sFrom`. I'd also suggest, like the two preceding comments, that you rethink this approach.

Comment: What is the structure of the prefix table?    The error suggests that there is not a field called Prefix in that table?

Comment: @Sparky, that's what I dont understand. There is 100% a column called prefix.

Comment: Try changing the AS Prefix to AS PrefixTbl or something.  The parser might be getting trip up on Prefix as a table name, column name, and field alias...     Just a thought

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you maybe forgetting to concatenate @sFrom to @sSql before you execute it? 
Try changing

```
SELECT @sFrom = ' FROM .....
```

to

```
SELECT @sSql = @sSql +  ' FROM .....
```

You can also try inserting a print statement of the sql you are about to execute to make sure you are executing what you think you're executing. ...

Also, what is @sFrom declared as? Perhaps it's getting truncated right before the last join and hence the error?

Hope that helps